# How to get all events from a facebook page using the opengraph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get all events from a Facebook page, so no posts, just the events. How can I achieve that with the opengraph api?

I tried the paramenters `event` and `user_events` but this returns nothing.

How can I get a json object containing all events and their data from a facebook page?

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information like how you make your API call and on which page you are trying to get the events from? Without a page access token you can only get public events of that specific page.

Comment: please add your code. user_events is a permission for the user, there is no relation to pages. what access token are you using? do you manage the page?

Comment: @luschn I am only looking for the correct parameter, not how to do it. My code already works, except the parameter is wrong. I don't manage the page and I have a page access token.

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/   You should use parameter `events` , which will give you a list of event nodes

Comment: /page-id/events would be the endpoint, as you can see in the api reference. btw, you cannot get a page token for pages you do not manage. that would be weird.

Comment: @luschn Yeah I got that, is it possible to combine the two in 1 object? So an object that contains both posts on a page and the events on a page?

Comment: see my answer about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint for events:

```
/page-id/events
```

The endpoint to get events and the feed in one call:

```
/page-id?fields=events,feed
```

...or with specific sub-fields:

```
/page-id?fields=events{name,description},feed
```